# Checking if there is an edit on a column on google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically, if there when the user edits column B, I want to send an email message to the address found in column D of the row that was edited. How can I do it with the Apps Script on Google Sheets?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MailApp.sendEmail()` with an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), like this:

```js
function sendEmailNotification(e) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 14 December 2022
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/74789336/13045193
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window but set up a trigger. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.');
  }
  if (!e.range || e.range.columnStart !== 2) {
    return;
  }
  const emailAddress = e.range.offset(0, 2).getDisplayValue();
  if (!emailAddress.match(/\w+@\w+\.\w+/i)) {
    return;
  }
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!sheet.getName().match(/^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i)) {
    return;
  }
  const emailSubject = 'I have trouble formulating a good question.';
  const emailContents = 'Cannot really tell what my real-world goal is either.';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, emailContents);
}
```

Comment: can you tell which numbers to modify to change the columns?

Comment: Column `B` is column number `2`, and the cell in the same row in column `D` is offset `0, 2` rows and columns from the cell in column `B`.

Comment: i get an error on executions:
`ReferenceError: range is not defined at sendEmailNotification(Code:10:24)`

Comment: Edited the answer to fix that. The `e.` bit was missing from one instance of `e.range`.

Comment: for the contents of the e-mail, how can i send the data of the row?

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Send email on an edit in column b

```
function sendEmailOnEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart !== 2) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(e.range.offset(0,2).getDisplayValue(),"Subject","Message");
  }
}
```